# Ionic 2 Alert Prompt

Tags: ionic2

I am using Ionic 2

Does anyone know how to make sure and [alert-prompt](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#alert-prompt) can be made to only accept numbers?

By default it can accept free text.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add
type:'number'

```
{
    name: 'phone',
    placeholder: 'phone',
    type: 'number'
  }
```

Check API docs
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/alert/AlertController/

Answer (score -2):

```
{
    name: 'phone',

    placeholder: 'phone',

    type: 'number'

 }
```

Comment: you have just past the above answer.